# Java installer with support for windows service

Tags: java, windows, service, installation

I'm looking for an free java installer with the ability to set up a windows service. As an example of such installer, I've been googling to find out which installer uses tomcat but I didn't succeed.

Any successful experiences?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly, Tomcat 4.X made use of the [Java Service Wrapper (click)](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/download.jsp).

You can go directly to the examples by clicking [here](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/example.html#TestWrapper-NT).

Answer (score 0):

[InstallAnywhere](http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/installanywhere.htm) supports creation of service using GUI or java API.